# Jump to line in nano

Tags: nano, virtual-consoles

When using `nano` in any of several terminal emulators <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> invokes `Enter line number, column number:` dialog. However when working from a virtual terminal e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> nothing happens. Why?

Comment: Have you checked whether the terminal emulator itself use some key bindings the same as the 'nano`, i.e. the override the key bindings.

Comment: are you using a different keyboard layout in the terminal?